# Сделать возможным в поле инпут только текст и пробел

Tags: jquery

```js
$('#cyr').on('keypress', function() {
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    var res = /[^а-яА-ЯїЇєЄіІёЁ ]/g.exec(that.value);
    that.value = that.value.replace(res, '');
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="cyr" />
```

Поставил такой код на пк работает нормально но на андроиде можно вводить все что хочешь. Сначала 1 букву вводишь и дальше все что хочешь пишется. Что не так с кодом?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Может так?

```js
$('#input').keydown(function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  return /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(charStr) || charCode == 8;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input">
```

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Прикрепил скриншот